# How to join two dataframes when only some dates in one dataframe is present between two other dates in other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2021-04-01 00:00:00','2021-05-01 00:00:00', '2021-05-02 00:00:00'],'end_date':['2021-04-01 00:11:00','2021-05-01 00:06:00', '2021-05-03 00:00:00'], 'eventname':['birthday', 'wedding', 'birthday'] })
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'event_date':['2021-04-01 00:06:00','2021-05-01 00:03:00', '2021-05-04 00:00:00'],'price':[100,200,500]})
df_A['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A.end_date)
df_A['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A.start_date)
df_B['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B.event_date)

df_A

    start_date  end_date    eventname
0   2021-04-01  2021-04-01 00:11:00 birthday
1   2021-05-01  2021-05-01 00:06:00 wedding
2   2021-05-02  2021-05-03 00:00:00 birthday

df_B

event_date  price
0   2021-04-01 00:06:00 100
1   2021-05-01 00:03:00 200
2   2021-05-04 00:00:00 500
```

I want to join them such that `event_date` column lies in between the `start_date` and `end_date` column of df_A. This is my code:

```
df_A.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_A['start_date'],df_A['end_date'],closed='both')
df_B['start_date'] = df_B['event_date'].apply(lambda x : df_A.iloc[df_A.index.get_loc(x)]['start_date'])
df_B
```

However, I get a keyerror as some of values on `event_date` column of df_B do not lie between any of the `start_date` and `end_date` of columns in df_A.

THis is my expected output:

```
event_date  price   start_date
0   2021-04-01 00:06:00 100 2021-04-01
1   2021-05-01 00:03:00 200 2021-05-01
2   2021-05-04 00:00:00 500 NaN
```

I tried using intersection but that works only if the values are exactly equal. How do I do this?

Comment: If the two dataframes are not too big, you can `merge` them with assigning each with `key=1`, and apply the logic on the merged dataframe.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL ? If you're using SQL please also tag your databases system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `start_date` and `end_date` do not overlap, create an interval index and merge your two dataframes:

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_A['start_date'], 
                                    df_A['end_date'],
                                    closed='both')

out = df_B.assign(interval=pd.cut(df_B['event_date'], bins)) \
          .merge(df_A.assign(interval=bins), on='interval', how='left')

print(out[['event_date', 'price', 'start_date']])

# Output:
           event_date  price start_date
0 2021-04-01 00:06:00    100 2021-04-01
1 2021-05-01 00:03:00    200 2021-05-01
2 2021-05-04 00:00:00    500        NaT
```

Comment: Thank you, this works excellently but in some cases I get `TypeError: Cannot convert Float64Index to dtype datetime64[ns]; integer values are required for conversion` even though my data format is the same. Do you know why that is? Else I will open a new question
`

Comment: I understood why I'm getting the error, when I try to join dataframes that have no event_date that lies in between any of the start_date and end_date intervals, it fails... is there a way to account for this as well?

Comment: It's strange because the last row of your dataframe (2021-05-04 00:00:00) does not fall into an interval.

Comment: Ah I meant if all the values of the ``interval`` resulted in NaNs, then it fails with the above mentioned error, I used an easy fix where I checked if the ``interval`` results in an empty Series, then I skipped the merge for that dataframe

Comment: Ok I understood. I though you will get an empty dataframe not an exception. (if my answer suits to your need, please consider to accept it. Thanks:))

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid a non-equi join, then do so; use a bucketing technique, similar to @Corralien's excellent answer, where the bins do not overlap (faster/more efficient). Another option, if possible, is to find a way to introduce merge joins, and maybe union your final output -> the steps may be longer, however, I feel if done right, it would be more efficient than a non-equi join. If however, you care only for the first match, then `pd.merge_asof` should suffice.

Back to the question :

One option is via the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df_A.conditional_join(
       df_B,  
       # column from left frame, column from right frame, comparision operator
       ('start_date', 'event_date', '<='), 
       ('end_date', 'event_date', '>='), 
       how = 'right')
   .filter(['event_date', 'price', 'start_date'])
)

           event_date  price start_date
0 2021-04-01 00:06:00    100 2021-04-01
1 2021-05-01 00:03:00    200 2021-05-01
2 2021-05-04 00:00:00    500        NaT
```

What it does is compare columns from `df_A` with `df_B`:

`('start_date', 'event_date', '<=')` means check if `start_date` from `df_A` is `<=` `event_date` from `df_B`. same concept applies to the other conditions. The parameter here is variable args, meaning you can pass as many conditions as possible. The columns must be same type (float vs float, integer vs integer, date vs date, ...).

Under the hood, it uses binary search for non-equi joins (primarily to avoid a cartesian join, which can be inefficient memory wise as the dataframe size grows); for range joins such as in this case, it uses a simple search to reduce the search space to get the matching rows.

The function can handle overlapping indices, as well as scenarios where the range join involves two different columns -> `a < b and c > d`.

You can have a look at more examples [here](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor-examples/conditional_join/)

Comment: can you explain this concept?

Comment: I get an empty dataframe when I try this, does it also work on timestamps with milliseconds?

Comment: It works on the sample data provided. Do you mind sharing more data containing seconds?

Comment: @user42 when you can kindly share a sample dataframe with the milliseconds, along with the expected output, so I can test and see where/why it fails. Thanks